# I am trying to make text fade in Unity, but the code in my for loop returns a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, game-development

I am making a mobile game in Unity, and I want to make some text fade out. I have created a for loop that increases the alpha value of the text's color by one 255 times. When I run the code, it gives me a NullReferenceException, saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Here is the for loop causing the problem.

```
   {
       for(int alphaVal = 0; alphaVal < 256; alphaVal++)
       {
           text.color = new Color(red, green, blue, alphaVal);
       }
   }
```

Comment: not enough info. In what line exactly you get the null exception?

Comment: Why not using animations? Add an animator and make fade in and out animations to the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Your `text` variable is not assigned. Make sure you drag it in through the inspector. Also, unitys color object does not accept 255 values. It accepts a float ranging from 0 to 1. Passing in anything higher than 1 will always result in a value of 1 (full alpha)